# DynamoDB Javascript – Query by primary key and array of range keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

New to DynamoDB and need to do the above query, but not sure how.  Here is what I'm trying currently, and I'm getting the error below.

Btw, I am using this javascript library w/ DynamoDB:  https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk

```
var ids = ['12313','12312313','12312313'];
var params = {
        TableName: 'apps',
        IndexName: 'state-app_id-index',
        KeyConditions: [
            DynamoDB.Condition("state", "EQ", "active"),
            DynamoDB.Condition("id", "IN", ids)
        ]
    };

    DynamoDB.query(params, function(error, response) {});
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

> ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: ComparisonOperator IN is not valid for L AttributeValue type

Answer (score 5):

[`KeyConditions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditions) does not support the `IN` operator. The documentation for `KeyCondition` says what operators it does support:

> For KeyConditions, only the following comparison operators are
>   supported:
>
> `EQ` | `LE` | `LT` | `GE` | `GT` | `BEGINS_WITH` | `BETWEEN`

The `EQ` operator only works for a single value as well:

> - `EQ` : Equal.
>
>   *AttributeValueList* can contain only one *AttributeValue* of type String, Number, or Binary (not a set type). If an item contains an AttributeValue element of a different type than the one specified in the request, the value does not match. For example, `{"S":"6"}` does not equal `{"N":"6"}`. Also, `{"N":"6"}` does not equal `{"NS":["6", "2", "1"]}`.

The restrictions are basically the same for [`KeyConditionExpression`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression), which is the newer, recommended way for filtering on keys. Here is a snippet from the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The condition must perform an equality test on a single hash key
>   value. **The condition can also perform one of several comparison tests
>   on a single range key value**. *Query* can use *KeyConditionExpression* to
>   retrieve one item with a given hash and range key value, or several
>   items that have the same hash key value but different range key values

In your case, you could build out the [`FilterExpression`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-FilterExpression) in a similar way as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067912/aws-dynamodb-multiple-ne-string-filters/29069240#29069240).

Comment: I'm after the same thing but as per your link `A FilterExpression does not allow key attributes. You cannot define a filter expression based on a partition key or a sort key.`. So back at square one.

Comment: Me too @StevendeSalas - seems like a huge limitation. Did you find a workaround? I'm going to perform a batch get first, then perform any additional filtering in memory - but this definitely seems like overkill for a rather simple query.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to use the IN statement is by using a filter Condition.
However Filter expression can only contain non-primary key attributes.
Thus the query you want to achieve is **NOT** possible with primary keys.
Something like this

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'apps',
    ...
    FilterExpression: "#id IN (:one,:two)",: 
...
```

Is only possible with non-primary key attributes

The workaround you can apply is using the batch get [item](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html)
Therefore instead of issuing one query issue multiples in one call and each condition shall contain a value from your ids array.

When it comes to batch get items be aware of the read capacity units ([batch get item in node.js](https://egkatzioura.wordpress.com/2016/07/20/query-dynamodb-items-with-node-js-part-2/)).